# OnLongClick() blocks the other clicks on the parent view

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I have a strange behavior, I use a RecyclerView to display a list.
Each item of this list is composed of a LinearLayout containing 2 TextViews. (It's a classic configuration).
I have an OnClickListener on the LinearLayout and an OnLongClickListener on the second TextView.

The problem is that the OnLongClickListener prevents the "normal clicks" to reach the LinearLayout.

To summarize:
If I click on the first TextView, the Layout is clicked.
If I click on the second TextView, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid this situation with your current `xml` file, you may need to make adjustment
Though if you want it with this design, you have to add `OnClickListener` to your second text that have `OnLongClickListener` and call inside it whatever you call on `linearView.OnClickListener` .

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked on TextView just disable all click of linear layout because at a time one click listener will work.

```
linearlayout.setClickable(false);
linearlayout.setEnabled(false);
```